# CentOS Master Boot Record Overwritten

Tags: centos, grub, system-recovery, alma-linux

On my `CentOS 7.7` box, I installed another drive and installed `AlmaLinux 9`.  Things went wrong at that point.  I thought I could just use the `BIOS` to choose which OS I wanted to load.  Isn't the case as apparently the **Master Boot Record** is overwritten.

I've reinstalled the grub:

```
/sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda
```

Now when it boots up, it ends up with the `grub` prompt.  I thought it would grab the volume from `/etc/fstab` and just load up.

```
grub>
```

How can I get this to work again?  I've not found anything that would suggest what needs to be changed to load the OS.

Any insight appreciated. Cheers

**Further info/feedback**:

I think this is going the wrong way.  What I want to do is to completely avoid `Alma` for the moment.  If I had known the installation of that option has caused trouble, then I wouldn't have done it.  I want to get this server back to its original state.  I don't know what happened, as I haven't changed anything on my `CentOS7` system.

So let's extricate `Alma` from the picture.  I might move there in the future.

I have an `SSD` that I'm loading up via `USB`, same version of `CentOS 7.7 v2003`.

Comment: Are you using UEFI/gpt or Old BIOS/MBR? And are both systems installed in same boot mode? Fix depends if UEFI or BIOS. This works with most Linux, but report can give us details to suggest best fix. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Both are UEFI.  I'm not well versed in this stuff.  How do I get the Bootinfo Summary Report?  My USB boot is same version and Troubleshooting just puts me into an Anaconda `/mnt/sysimage` which I can then `chroot`.

Comment: Do the instructions on using ppa not work? It does require some typical Linux tools usually installed by default in Ubuntu, but available in almost all distributions. Or you can download the Boot-Repair ISO which is based on Lubuntu. It just is not always updated as often as the ppa.

Comment: I have never seen this before and will have to look it up when I hit the desk.

Comment: ok, if this is UEFI, then the MBR doesn't matter, simple as that. That's great news! because it's far easier to just boot from a life stick, chroot into your AlmaLinux and re-install the UEFI shim to get an UEFI boot loader entry.

Comment: …which leaves me at the `grub>` prompt

Comment: nope. That means you've selected a grub boot stub instead of the boot stub of the OS you really wanted to boot.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've left some updated notes in the OP.  I want to get back to the original state of this machine.

Comment: @Rich_F but that makes no practical difference. All you need to do is take my answer and mentally replace "alma" with "centos" in every place.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, will take a look.  Probably questions later.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the same described below works 100% identically for CentOS 7; just mentally replace alma with centos; find the centos root partition instead of the alma one, and so on.

---

So, since you say you're using UEFI to boot

1. The MBR is ignored by UEFI. So, that's not the problem! The problem seems to be that you boot into GRUB from UEFI, and you somehow broke that.
2. We can repair GRUB, to be able to chainload your Almalinux kernel.
3. To do so, you'll need a live USB stick that allows you to do things on your unbootable Alma. I just download fedora live USB images, but I bet the almalinux installer USB image works just as beautifully.
4. You'll need to boot from that stick.

- as soon as booted, identify the root volume / partition of your Almalinux. I just run `sudo blivet-gui` and look graphically. Let's say that partition is called /dev/sdx2.
- you want to do the following in a root shell (`sudo -s`):

```bash
mkdir -p /alma
mount /dev/sdx2 /alma
mount -o bind /dev /alma/dev
mount -t proc proc /alma/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /alma/sys
mount -t devpts pts /alma/dev/pts
chroot /alma
```

congratulations! You now have a root shell in your (unbootable) Alma linux. Nice. We can rescue "from within". First we mount all file systems, especially the /boot/EFI one:

```bash
# (in the chroot shell we opened above)
mount -a
mount # check if the output of this lists /boot/EFI
mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf # resolv.conf is usually dynamically generated, we need to trick a bit here.
dnf reinstall grub2-efi grub2-pc grub2-pc-modules grub2-tools-efi grub2-tools-extra shim-x64
rm /etc/resolv.conf
mv /etc/resolv.conf.bak /etc/resolv.conf
exit
# if the above looks like it worked:
systemctl reboot
```

Comment: `mount /dev/sda /cent`
# mount: /dev/sda is already mounted or /cent busy, both in anaconda main and shell
Cannot move forward.  Can this go to chat?

Comment: that's great! means /dev/sda is already mounted. What does `mount` without any arguments say?

Comment: About 40 lines.  Anything specific?  I can't see anything relevant to `/dev/sda`.

Comment: `mount` does not mention `/boot/EFI`.  There is no `/etc/resolv.conf`.  And I'm not sure if I'm past `chroot /mnt/sysimage` or in bash as `root`.